# .NET Send multiple emails asynchronously and thread-safe

Tags: c#, multithreading, email, asynchronous

**I need to send *multiple* emails *asynchronously*** in order not to get the main thread blocked. In simple terms: I don't want to wait for the complete operation of having all mails sent; instead, I'd like to receive each mail delivery status on a callback.

For that, I'm using:

```
smtpClient.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(SendMailCompletedCallback);
smtpClient.SendAsync( mailMessage, Guid.NewGuid );
```

`SendMailCompletedCallback` complies with SendCompleted event definition: `private void SendMailCompletedCallback(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)`

SendAsync() method blocks the main thread, so it does not spawn different threads for each email sending. **Why I'm looking for different threads?** Because while sending many emails fast, on the callback I'm getting this error on the *e.Error* property of the *AsyncCompletedEventArgs*:

> Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server
>   response was: 4.7.0 Temporary System Problem

And, as far as I understand, it's because the SMTP client cannot handle multiple email async sendings without overlapping on its own thread.
One easy solution I've heard is to create a new instance of the SMTP client for each email to be sent, but unfortunately I could not suceed doing that either.

Could anyone please provide me a code that works? Thanks in advance! :)

**UPDATE:**
This would be full code..

```
var mailMessage = new MailMessage { //.. };
var smtpClient = new SmtpClient { //.. };

smtpClient.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(SendMailCompletedCallback);
smtpClient.SendAsync( mailMessage, Guid.NewGuid );
```

And the Callback is as following:

```
private void SendMailCompletedCallback(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{            
    if (e.Error.IsNotNull())
    {
        // here is where I get the error message mentioned above       
    }
    ((SmtpClient)sender).Dispose();
}
```

Comment: I think your idea of having a separate SMTP client per thread was a good one.  Can you post the code you tried for that?  We can probably help you getting that one to work.

Comment: I've removed the `C#` from your title as it isn't needed - the question isn't *about* C#. I've left the thread safety bit in even though your problem probably has nothing to do with thread safety.

Comment: Fair enough. I've then added ".NET" as I am using .NET framework indeed (I wouldn't like people getting confused thinking I'm using php, delphi, etc.)

Comment: You don't need to add that either.... It's a misconception amongst new(er) users - there is the temptation or inclination to use tags in the title to differentiate the question from other platforms, but in effect those words are for classification therefore they should be in tags not the title (sorry, long sentence :) IOW the usage of the C# tag already shows it is .Net.